# A "Simple' Scala question but took me long time to debug

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Please check the two pieces of script as above.

`genComb4(lst)` works since I put `z <- genComb4(xs)` before `i <- 0 to x._2` in the for-comprehension; `genComb(lst)` does not work since I change the order of these two lines in for-comprehension.

It took me almost half day to find this bug, but I cannot explain it by myself. Could you tell me why this happened?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
// generate combinations
val nums = Vector(1, 2, 3)
val strs = Vector('a', 'b', 'c')
val lst: List[(Char, Int)] = strs.zip(nums).toList

def genComb4(lst: List[(Char, Int)]): List[List[(Char, Int)]] = lst match {
  case Nil => List(List())
  case x :: xs =>
    for {
      z <- genComb4(xs)  // correct
      i <- 0 to x._2     // correct
    } yield ( (x._1, i) :: z)
}
genComb4(lst)

def genComb(lst: List[(Char, Int)]): List[List[(Char, Int)]] = lst match {
  case Nil => List(List())
  case x :: xs =>
    for {
      i <- (0 to x._2)  // wrong
      z <- genComb(xs)  // wrong
    } yield ( (x._1, i) :: z)
}
genComb(lst)
```

Comment: for-comprehensions in Scala are syntactic sugar over `map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter`. I will recommoned that you start using the syntactic sugar only after you can understand and implement the functionality in terms of `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter`. Just stick to `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter` in your learning phase and you will understand with practice.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It's because of different types of container in `for comprehension`. When you start `for-comprehension` from line: `i <- (0 to x._2)` it's set type of result container as `IndexedSeq` but in case where first line is `z <- genComb4(xs)` the type of result container is `List`, take a look:

```
val x = 'a' -> 2
val indices: Seq[Int] = 0 to x._2
val combs: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = genComb4(List(x))

// indexed sequence
val indicesInFor: IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] = for {
  i <- 0 to x._2
} yield (x._1, i)

// list 
val combsInFor: List[List[(Char, Int)]] = for {
  z <- genComb4(List(x))
} yield z
```

so for make your second case is working, you should cast `(0 to x._2).toList`:

```
val indicesListInFor: List[(Char, Int)] = for {
  i <- (0 to x._2).toList
} yield (x._1, i)
```

result code should be:

```
def genComb(lst: List[(Char, Int)]): List[List[(Char, Int)]] = lst match {
  case Nil => List(List())
  case x :: xs =>
    for {
      i <- (0 to x._2).toList
      z <- genComb(xs)
    } yield ( (x._1, i) :: z)
}
genComb(lst)
```

You should remember about type of starting line in *for-comprehension* and *inheritance of scala collections*. If *next* types in `for-comprehension` can't be converted by inheritance rules to the *first expression line* type you should take care about it by yourself.

Good practise is unwrap `for-expression` into `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter` functions, then you will find miss-typing or something else faster.

useful links:

- [how does yield work, scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)
- [quick review of scala for-comprehensions](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/quick-review-scala-for-expressions/)
- [for-expressions, scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift and complete explanation, which help me a lot.